# How do I true a trailer wheel?

Tags: trailer, wheel-truing

We use a Croozer Kid For Two, and we love it. I replaced the tires recently, but badly: one twisted, making the wheel look like it was out-of-true -- to the extent people started stopping me to tell me my "wheel was buckled". The twist was easily fixed, but it got me thinking.

How *would* I true a rim from a two-wheeled trailer? My own jig assumes a through-axle, but the trailer uses cantilever axles.

Comment: I think you’d have to modify your wheel truing jig so that the cantilevered axle would work. A bike shop that handles wheelchairs would have one of these.

Comment: Note that trailer wheels don’t bear a lot of weight and so just doing it by eye would likely be fine.

Comment: I would skip using the truing stand and just true the wheel on the trailer.  You can generally clamp a strip of something to the frame to act as an indicator, so you can more easily zero in on the worst spots.  Dishing is harder, but there should no need to dish accurately in most cases.

Comment: I use my thumb as a gauge, and spin the wheel on the trailer.  It works well enough, and the trailer has no rim brakes so perfectly true is not needed.

Comment: @DanielRHicks : I haven't the rep to vote, so have a virtual(?!) +1. Would you please make your comment an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would skip using the truing stand and just true the wheel on the trailer. You can generally clamp a strip of something to the frame to act as an indicator (have it stick out and just brush the rim, kind of like a rim brake pad), so you can more easily zero in on the worst spots.

Dishing/centering is harder without a stand, but there should no need to dish/center a trailer wheel that accurately in most cases.